# How to avoid CSS compilation to SWF in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

It seems it isn't possible at runtime to change styling defined in CSS files, ex.: colors. This is seemingly because the CSS files are compiled into SWF.

Is it possible to externalize styling information in CSS (or any other format) without compiling it to SWF file so that it can be changed easily at runtime just as normal CSS can be changed when it is used in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We eventually found a way of applying styling, without having a compilation step. We are sticking to basics.

We defined a configuration XML file and using `onPre` method of `mx:application` we read this XML file and applied the styling to UI components.

This approach ensured that the styling is centralized at least at application level and most importantly it is now possible to quickly try out new styles by changing the configuration file and refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Flex 3, [Loading an external CSS file](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Text_15.html)  and hopes similarly can be used for Flex 4 as

- Load CSS File using [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html)
- List item Parse it with [StyleSheet](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html)  **parseCSS** function
- Assign it to Application

Also see [StyleSheet](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/flash/text/StyleSheet.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Hopes that helps

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [this documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f8c.html) answers all your questions. You have to use some CSS at compile time but you can load and apply another one at runtime without problem.